# i receive an error: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendkeys'

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

i have this code on a practise page:

```
**from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="G:\Selenium Testing\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#name").send_keys("option3")**
```

and i receive this error:

```
***driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#name").sendkeys("option3")
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendkeys'***
```

please help me with this

i also tried using this import statement:

```
***from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys***
```

Comment: please share the dom part

Answer (score 0):

In python it is

```
send_keys
```

not

```
sendkeys("option3")
```

`sendkeys("option3")` is basically in **Selenium - Java bindings**.

so your effective code would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#name").send_keys("option3")
```

Comment: sorry, my code got edited by mistake, i wrote the code in the same format  but still, i receive the same error error

Comment: If you are keep on seeing this error `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendkeys'***` .. then in your code there must be some place where you are exactly calling the `sendKeys`

Comment: Also, you have shared `***driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#name").sendkeys("option3")
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendkeys'***`.. if you had copied from console then my solution should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys("option3")
```

I've just tested it in the console, and it works for me.

EDIT:

Actually, `find_element_by_css_selector("#name")` works too, so the problem lies somewhere else...

Perhaps do a `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#name").click()` first, and then `send_keys("option3")`